# Why can't I install Worms Armageddon on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, worms-armageddon

After I tell it to install, a setup page comes up and says it is opening the installer. Once it loads to 100% it disappears and then nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running it in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click setup file
2. Select Compatibility Tab
3. Tick 'Run this program in compatibility mode for:'
4. Select an older Windows (XP should do fine I think) from the drop down menu.

See if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try the unofficial installer to get the game to set up on Windows 7 64-bit or later.

http://worms2d.info/Automatic_Installer

Then be sure to visit the official site for the latest patch. You will still need the game CD.

http://wormsarmageddon.team17.com/